# Xamarin axml, xml Intellisense not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I started using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition with Version 15.7.4. and Xamarin Version 4.10.0 and need to work on Xamarin native android application.

But Auto fill suggestions not coming in `xml and axml` files. Intellisense working for widget names(Like `TextView, EditText` etc.) In layout axml files. But, for widget properties (Like `android:layout_width, android:gravity` etc.) it isn't working. Where as in `styles.xml, menu.xml` suggestions not coming at all. I check with following ways.

1) XML - Schemas > `android-layout-xml.xsd` and `schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd` files are exists

2) File opened as XML (Text) Editor

3) I didn't find `Resharper` in Tools

Also, Is there any way to change Xamarin keyboard shortcuts to Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: You can use `Tab` key in keyboard to auto fill.Unfortunately, some property can not show in Xamarin like Android Studio or Eclipse .I think this will be updated in later version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a Xamarin developer for almost two years I have come to terms with the fact that the Xamarin Android intellisense has never worked as it is expected.

It has **a lot of bugs and issues** (Links below) which have made it a real pain in the neck, But there are workarounds which you have already mentioned above and if those do not work for you trust me nothing will.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/118384/android-designer-does-not-work-well
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/125879/designer-not-loading-layout-at-all
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76851/visual-studio-2015-android-designer-not-working
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82082/android-designer-not-working-in-visual-studio-enterprise-2015
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6258/android-designer-doesnt-work-in-vs-2012
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99268/xamarin-android-designer-not-working.html

**My suggestions**:

Android studio provides you with a very strong designer and hence I would simply suggest you use Android studio to write down your XML and then just copy paste it to your Xamarin AXML/XML files and it should work like a charm, Same can be done for any other time of files such as strings or styles XML.

For changing the visual studio shortcuts you can simply check the [following guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017)

Comment: there won't be any issue if i prepare layouts, styles, drawables in Android studio, later i copy it to xamarin?

Comment: Of course there won't be in the end it is Android Remember and if there would be why would i recommend it to you?