# my activity_main.axml in visual studio 2017 xamarin android app don't have any layout design showed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

Hello and good day developers, I am here again to ask you some
 question-related to my new build project in visual studio 2017 xamarin
the android app.used blank app..the issue is I can't see my layout design,
also when I drag and drop a button, textbox etc, but when I click the
 centre of the white background there is a rectangular blueprint show
 or blue border...

**Note: this is a built-in code.**

> // activity_main.axml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

// MainActivity.cs

```
    using Android.App;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Support.V7.App;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Widget;

    namespace MhylesOrdering
    {
        [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
        public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
        {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            }
        }
    }
```

> // ScreeenShot

[image]

> Now I added new layout which is the layout1.axml but the issue is
>   still there

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous can you explain what exactly is the problem

Comment: Sir @G.hakim my main.axml or activity_main.axml have no preview display when i click it, it will display only a plain white background even when I drag and drop a button the button in invisible but, when I click in the middle it will display a rectangular blue border..

Comment: I see can you give me your build tool and version details like Xamarin, Visual studio and everything else that is related? Thanks!

Comment: ok Sir @G.hakim I use VS2017 Version 15.9.5, .net Framework version 4.7.03056, Xamarin - 4.12.3.78, Xamarin Designer - 4.16.13, Xamarin Android SDK - 9.1.5.0 and Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK - 12.2.1.12, and used windows 10 with 64bit OS, X64 BP..

Comment: I have a feeling that your designer is not getting loaded properly for some reason, which should not be happening in your xml code for `activity_main` try setting a different background color and see if that reflects or not, just confirming a theory!

Comment: yes Sir I think that is the problem..can you advice me or suggest some solution for this?

Comment: So, I guess the background colour did not reflect?

Comment: I any case in my `VS2017 v15.9.7` it works properly, can you upgrade to the latest release?

Comment: ok sir I try to upgrade into the latest Version

Comment: Yes sure it will not take a lot of time revert if it works or not later

Comment: Sir @G.hakim I finish updating but the issue is still there..

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot ?

Comment: Screenshot uploaded

Comment: Do one thing add a new axml file and then try opening that and see if that works for you!

Comment: Sir @LeoZhu screenshot uploaded

Comment: Sir @G.hakim now I added new axml file but still the same out put..

Comment: Then I guess you will have to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809931/7462031

Comment: I do everything inside that link but, it is still not working..